# Sonatype nexus repository oss - Retrieve ".module" instead of component

Tags: grails, dependencies, artifactory, nexus, sonatype

I've an on-premise instance of Sonatype Nexus Repo, then I've setted various proxys to retrieve maven artifacts from various external artifactorys (ex.: https://repo.grails.org/ui/native/repo1-cache, https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/, etc...)

When I try to install my application dependencies, if those are not present in my artifactory, Nexus automatically tries to retrieve those through the proxy.

Finally, the issue is when one precise library doesn't exist in the repo but it returns an html "module" file that it is the jfrog picture of the repo, trying to load the library requested and not the json.

Nexus version : Sonatype Nexus Repository OSS 3.61.0-02

Screenshots:

- [application dependency install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exsva.png)
- [artifactory library retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycvWR.png)

I tryed to apply "auto-block" rules and "routing rules" without success.

The only thing that it works is to place, in my application, the dependencies by "working" order. Instead, I was expecting to nexus do this for me.

Is there any way to apply a "pause" and if nothing is returned, then look into the "next" repo in the repo list? Other solution?

Really appreciate your help !